# How to send command when no match using expect?

Tags: expect

Is it possible to send a default command when expect doesn't match anything?

eg I want to send enter until a match is made?

```
set timeout 60

expect {
  timeout {
    puts "Failed to find foo"
    exit 1
  }

  "foo" {
    exit
  }

  default {
    send "\r"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a prompt that says something like 'hit enter to continue" ?

Comment: it is a large table that loads one line at a time.

Comment: And you have to hit enter after each line?

Comment: that is correct. the line will load, and pressing enter will load the next line to be processed by expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can expect the line ending to send a carriage return: expect translates line endings to `\r\n`

```
expect {
  timeout {
    puts "Failed to find foo"
    exit 1
  }

  "foo" {
    exit
  }

  "\r\n" {
    send "\r"
    exp_continue
  }
}
```

Comment: how will foo be evaluated since the line with foo also has \r\n.

Comment: of course. my error. the foo pattern has to come first. Edited

Comment: Doh. Let me give this is a try tomorrow!